Entity Framework Core ToView still creating Table in Migration
This all applies to Entity Framework Core v8.0.10, .NET 8, and Oracle 19.0.0.
I have this view in my database:
CREATE VIEW VW_TESTVIEW 
AS
    SELECT 'THIS IS A TEST' AS EXAMPLE
    FROM DUAL;

This just returns a single record with a column called EXAMPLE with the content THIS IS A TEST:

In my .NET 8 application, I have added this class:
public class VW_TestView
{
    public string Example { get; set; }
}

In my DbContext.OnModelCreating method I have added the following code:
modelBuilder
    .Entity<VW_TestView>(x =>
    {
        x.HasNoKey();
        x.ToView("VW_TESTVIEW");
    });

Additionally I have added the following property the DbContext:
public virtual DbSet<VW_TestView> TestViews { get; set; }

When I run Add-Migration ExampleView, the resulting Migration.Up method has this CreateTable:
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "VW_TESTVIEW",
    columns: table => new
    {
        EXAMPLE = table.Column<string>(type: "NVARCHAR2(2000)", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
    });

As a result, applying this migration fails because an object already exists with the same name.
If I ignore the entity from the model, I still cannot use the TestViews DbSet as it returns this error:

System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'VW_TestView' because this type is not included in the model for the context


What is the right way to have a class representing a database view with EF Core?
Why doesn't ToView do what it says it should do? ("Configures the view that the entity type maps to when targeting a relational database.")


Looks like 'OnModelCreating' is not called or your configuring code is not called. In this case  EF throws such exception.

Ah no, it's definitely being called. I meant that I was excluding it with .Ignore<VW_TestView>()`.

Can you try to do taht on clean project. Something went wrong, ToView() is introduced to do not create table migration.

There is a "Not planned" issue related to your problem in dotnet efcore repo: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/4561
To answer your questions:
What is the right way to have a class representing a database view with EF Core?
I think you did just fine to represent the view.
Why doesn't ToView do what it says it should do? ("Configures the view that the entity type maps to when targeting a relational database.")
It actually doing what is supposed to do.
I think what is going to work for you is that you could delete the migrationBuilder.CreateTable(.. to create the view in Migration.Up
Do not specify the view's creation in your migration "Up" if you do not like it do to so...

Every single migration is going to end up with an incorrect CreateTable that I and my team will have to remember to remove before updating the database. It's totally backwards and defeats the point of using EF...

There is a "Not planned"  issue to your problem in dotnet efcore repo. What I've suggested is in there, you could take a look : https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/4561
